# Retain legend and square aspect ratio in ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to create a plot that contains a legend and a "square" shape with equal aspect ratio. I was able to achieve this in the "p" object in the code below using ggplot2(). However, when I ran ggplotly() on the "p" object, the legend disappeared and the "square" shape with equal aspect ratio also disappeared. Below, I show two images showing the difference. The left image shows the "p" object with the legend and an equal aspect ratio. The x=y line in red perfectly intersects the bottom-left and top-right corners of the image. The right image shows the ggplotly(p) output where the legend is gone and the square aspect ratio is also gone. The x=y line no longer perfectly intersects the bottom-left and top-right corners of the image.

[image: Comparison of the two plots]

My MWE code is included below:

```
library(hexbin)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID", 1:1010), A.1 = c(rep(0.5, 1000), abs(rnorm(10))), A.2 = c(rep(0.5, 1000), abs(rnorm(10))), B.1 = c(rep(0.5, 1000), abs(rnorm(10))), B.2 = c(rep(0.5, 1000), abs(rnorm(10))), C.1 = c(rep(0.5, 1000), abs(rnorm(10))), C.2 = c(rep(0.5, 1000), abs(rnorm(10))), C.3 = c(rep(0.5, 1000), abs(rnorm(10))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

sampleIndex <- which(sapply(colnames(dat), function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"[.]"))[1]) %in% c("A", "C"))
datSel <- dat[,c(1, sampleIndex)]

sampleIndex1 <- which(sapply(colnames(datSel), function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"[.]"))[1]) %in% c("A"))
sampleIndex2 <- which(sapply(colnames(datSel), function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"[.]"))[1]) %in% c("C"))
minVal = min(datSel[,-1])
maxVal = max(datSel[,-1])
maxRange = c(minVal, maxVal)
xbins= 10
buffer = (maxRange[2]-maxRange[1])/(xbins/2)
x <- c()
y <- c()
for (i in 1:length(sampleIndex1)){
  for (j in 1:length(sampleIndex2)){
    x <- c(x, unlist(datSel[,(sampleIndex1[i])]))
    y <- c(y, unlist(datSel[,(sampleIndex2[j])]))
  }
}

h <- hexbin(x=x, y=y, xbins=xbins, shape=1, IDs=TRUE, xbnds=maxRange, ybnds=maxRange)
hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  hexID = h@cell, counts = h@count)
attr(hexdf, "cID") <- h@cID

my_breaks = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 1000)
p <- ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts, hexID=hexID)) + geom_hex(stat="identity") + geom_abline(intercept = 0, color = "red", size = 0.25) + labs(x = "A", y = "C") + coord_fixed(xlim = c(-0.5, (maxRange[2]+buffer)), ylim = c(-0.5, (maxRange[2]+buffer))) + theme(aspect.ratio=1)
p <- p + scale_fill_gradient(name = "count", trans = "log", breaks = my_breaks, labels = my_breaks, guide="legend")

ggplotly(p)
ggplotly(p) %>% layout(height = 200, width = 200)
ggplotly(p, height=400, width=400)
```

As you can see, I tried a few different approaches to creating the ggplotly(p) output. I received warnings as follows:

```
 Warning messages:
1: Aspect ratios aren't yet implemented, but you can manually set a suitable height/width 
2: Aspect ratios aren't yet implemented, but you can manually set a suitable height/width 
3: Specifying width/height in layout() is now deprecated.
Please specify in ggplotly() or plot_ly()
```

However, I am uncertain how to resolve this warning and the problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I removed the line `rm(list=ls())` from start of your code. If someone pastes this inadvertently into their acrtive R session, they will lose all their existig objects

Comment: what libraries do you use? Please add to MWE.  `hexbin` and `hcell2xy` not found

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial solution, it fixes the x = y line and square aspect ratio, but uses a bit of a workaround for the legend problem.

The aspect ratio issue is simple, in the latest version plotly changed so that now `height =` and `width =` go in `ggplotly()`, not `layout()` as in the previous version.  Unfortunately some of the online documentation still seems to specify the old formatting.

I could not get your custom legend and scale to show in plotly, and incompatibility with ggplot legends seems to be a documented plotly bug for some types of ggplots.  The best solution I could think of was to create a column in your dataframe for log counts, and then plot log counts so that the default legend showed the colors and scale you wanted.

```
# add a column for log count so default scale/legend can be used
hexdf$log_counts <- log(hexdf$counts)

p <- ggplot(hexdf, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex(stat="identity", aes(fill = log_counts)) + # log counts, not  counts
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, color = "red", size = 0.25) +
  labs(x = "A", y = "C") +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-0.5, (maxRange[2]+buffer)),
              ylim = c(-0.5, (maxRange[2]+buffer))) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

p 

# set width > height to allow room for legend
# plot looks close to 1:1 to me, but may need to adjust width slightly
ggplotly(p, height = 400, width = 500)
```

Which produces

[image]